# Retrieving data from multiple parquet files into one dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, parquet

I want to start by saying this is the first time I work with Parquet files. I have a list of 2615 parquet files that I downloaded from an S3 bucket and I want to read them into one dataframe. They follow the same folder structure and I am putting an example below:

`/Forecasting/as_of_date=2022-02-01/type=full/export_country=Spain/import_country=France/000.parquet'`

The file name `000.parquet` is always the same, irrespective of folder.

I saved all of the file locations using the following function:

```
import os
def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return r
```

This generates a list of all file locations, exactly like in the folder example above.

The next thing I tried was using DASK to read all of the parquet files into a dask dataframe but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
dask_df = dd.read_parquet(data_files)
```

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to fix it, although I understand where the issue is. It's because the files contain the columns `export_country` and `import_country`, which are also partitions:

```
ValueError: No partition-columns should be written in the 
file unless they are ALL written in the file.
```

Another solution I tried using was iterating through each parquet file using pandas and combining everything into one dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in data_files:
    data = pd.read_parquet(f,engine = 'pyarrow')
    df = df.append(data)
```

This seems to take ages and my kernel dies due to no more RAM available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variation of @Learning is a mess's answer, but using `dd.concat`:

```py
from dask.dataframe import read_parquet, concat
dask_df = concat([read_parquet(f) for f in data_files])
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this worked perfectly. Now I can use dask to filter out a lot of the rows I don't need and hopefully transform the rest into a pandas df.

Answer (score 3):

It's faster to do a single concat compared to append multiple times:

```py
df = pd.concat((pd.read_parquet(f, engine = 'pyarrow') for f in data_files))
```

but I doubt it helps with the memory limitation.

Answer (score 0):

### In Pandas 1.3 +

You can just read the folder directly, and pandas will concat them for you:

```
df = pd.read_parquet("path/to/folder/")
df.head()
```